# Chrome Dev-Tools Bug?

Tags: google-chrome-devtools

When i upload several files with [a JQuery File Upload](http://blueimp.github.com/jQuery-File-Upload/) Network Panel in Chrome Dev tools show the same response for two different requests (header data in Network panel is differnt too):

[image: Chrome Network Panel]
But real data is ok. Firefox Firebug show the truth respons.

Is it a known bug?

p.s. Chrome version is: 21.0.1180.89 m

Answer (score -1):

probably, I had something similar, but usually when I open and close the  console it works

Comment: not for me :(. When i toggle DevTool - network panel Flush. And the situation replayd.